# install matplotlib with pip when pygtk is in non standard location

Tags: linux, python, gtk, matplotlib

I have installed PyGTK 2.24.0 in `/software/pygtk-2.24.0/gcc` directory. Is there any way without rewrite the setup program how to install matplotlib with pip?

Simple `pip install matplotlib` builds matplotlib without GTK support. I have even tried to put `/software/pygtk-2.24.0/gcc` and `/software/pygtk-2.24.0/gcc/lib/python2.7/site-packages` to *setup.cfg* basedirlist variable and also in the list in function *get_base_dirs()* in setupext.py, in matplotlib build dir, but didn't succeed. Also tried the last matplotlib from git.

I suppose there should be sufficient to have correctly set up the $PYTHONPATH, $LD_LIBRARY_PATH and $PKG_CONFIG_PATH which I have. Is there anything like config.log to see what really happened that setup.py doesn't recognize the PyGTK install location?

I am able to do without any problem `>>> import pygtk` but `>>> import gtk` causes "not found" answer from Python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in my last sentence and in the demo script of PyGTK. Without successful `>>> import gtk` cannot be matplotlib compiled with PyGTK support.

I had not correctly set `$PYTHONPATH`, which should not only point to `/software/pygtk-2.24.0/gcc/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, but also to `/software/pygtk-2.24.0/gcc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0`. So

```
export PYTHONPATH=/software/pygtk-2.24.0/gcc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0:/software/pygtk-2.24.0/gcc/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

after PyGTK installation to my non standard directory has done it's job.